# How to reconstruct 2D flat image from a series of pictures of a tube

Tags: 3d, reconstruction, panorama

I have pictures of an oesophagus (ie a tube) taken under standard white light looking down the tube. I have about 10 images taken over 20cm in series. The image looks forward down into the tube and examples can be found [here](http://www.gastrolab.net/pa-170.htm). Each image is taken serially down the tube at the same session and the centre is positioned largely the same in all the pictures. I would like to be able to combine these images into one (I guess 3D cylinder) in order to then create a flat 2D surface image of the surface lining the tube. Is this possible?

Comment: I assume you mean that you would like to "cut" the tube and flatten it. Do you wonder how to project points of the images into a single 2D image?

Comment: Thinking about it I suppose its two questions 1. Is it possible to create a 3D image of a cylinder from several 2D images and 2. How to then project the points of the cylinder cut down its y axis onto a single 2D image